Call to a member function get() on bool
I'm facing an issue with a Call to a member function get() on bool error message. I've already enabled the debug status and I will present that in this post.
Let me explain what happened:
I've tried to add a new position in templateDetails.xml and by adding a new position I've also added settings:"class" in brackets. After that the Call to a member function get() on bool error showed up and now I'm stuck and don't know what to do.
here is the debug log as well:
Function    Location

() - JROOT\administrator\components\com_templates\tmpl\templates\default.php:101
include() - JROOT\libraries\src\MVC\View\HtmlView.php:416
Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\HtmlView->loadTemplate() - JROOT\libraries\src\MVC\View\HtmlView.php:204
Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\HtmlView->display() - JROOT\administrator\components\com_templates\src\View\Templates\HtmlView.php:125
Joomla\Component\Templates\Administrator\View\Templates\HtmlView->display()  JROOT\libraries\src\MVC\Controller\BaseController.php:697
Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->display()  JROOT\administrator\components\com_templates\src\Controller\DisplayController.php:68
Joomla\Component\Templates\Administrator\Controller\DisplayController->display() JROOT\libraries\src\MVC\Controller\BaseController.php:730
Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute()  JROOT\libraries\src\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher.php:143
Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher->dispatch()    JROOT\libraries\src\Component\ComponentHelper.php:361
Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent()  JROOT\libraries\src\Application\AdministratorApplication.php:150
Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()  JROOT\libraries\src\Application\AdministratorApplication.php:195
Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute() JROOT\libraries\src\Application\CMSApplication.php:306
Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute() JROOT\administrator\includes\app.php:58
require_once()   JROOT\administrator\index.php:32

thank you all for your help!

You will need to provide more details to assist anyone who might be attempting to help you. To start with in which template did you change templateDetails.xml? Can you post the code that you added/changed.

I'm using Helix Ultimate 2.1.1. I just added the <position settings:"class">name_of_the_position. I was able to do a recovery from a backup so now that issue is gone. But for the future reference it would be great to know what is going on when adding this simple code. with only  tag it worked fine, by adding the "settings:"class"" the problems began.

That's invalid XML syntax. Should be settings="class", not settings:"class".

Thank you very much!
